# What is default directory of File.Open?

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-4.0

I have this code:

```
Stream f = File.Open("data.majid", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
```

Where will be file created?

Comment: Don't use relative paths unless you are in total control of the working directory. Always safer to use an absolute path. The main exception is console apps where the working directory should be considered an input parameter to the program.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the `File.Open` MSDN documentation:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9skfh7s.aspx)

> The *path* parameter is permitted to specify relative or absolute path information. Relative path information is interpreted as relative to the current working directory. To obtain the current working directory, see [GetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Usually the directory where the process was started from. This is the current working directory.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The current directory is distinct from the original directory, which is the one from which the process was started.

Comment: No it is not! Relative paths are resolved relative to the process working directory. End of story.

Answer (score 1):

From *[`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9skfh7s.aspx)*;

> The path parameter is permitted to specify relative or absolute path
>   information. Relative path information is interpreted as relative to
>   the current working directory. To obtain the current working
>   directory, see **GetCurrentDirectory**.

Check out [`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx)

> The current directory is distinct from the original directory, which
>   is the one from which the process was started.

Answer (score 0):

it will store in current directory . that your application will run

e.g :

if you call `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();` it will return :

> "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0"

Answer (score 0):

Additionally:

- the working directory can be changed in VisualStudio project settings
  Project | Properties | Debug
- if you create a shortcut to the application for a user you can specify the "Start in" property