# c# Where does a path with no beginning default to?

Tags: c#

```
Stream stream = new FileStream("My File", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
```

If I have a code like this, the path of the stream defaults to bin\Debug where the .exe is located. But if the .exe was to be in another directory, would the path default to there? Would it always default to the same directory where the .exe is?

Comment: try it out......

Comment: Learn about the _current directory_.

Comment: @HimBromBeere - don't just try it out, because you might be misled by the result, e.g. into thinking it is the application base directory (as one answer, now deleted, suggested).  Instead, look up the documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is default directory of File.Open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000848/what-is-default-directory-of-file-open)

Answer (score 2):

The root will be the current working directory for the application. This doesn't have to be the same as the exe location, and it can change during execution.

For example if in a command line you are in the directory `C:\foo` and you run your application like so `C:\boo\my.exe` the path will be relative to `C:\foo`

You can find or change the working directory using the `Enviroment.CurrentDirectory` property

Comment: "... the working directory for the application" - not "for the application"; it can change while the application is running.

Comment: @Joe edited to reflect your feedback, you are right it read like the working directory was fixed which it is not.

Answer (score 0):

The file will always be written to the current "Working Directory". You can find out the full path to this location by calling `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory`.